# ActiveRecord: no such table for unrelated table, but only on one server

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I'm trying to set an attribute in an ActiveRecord table. I have the following file which works on one server, but gives an error on the other.

```
require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'

require_relative 'models/master'
$CONFIG = YAML.load_file('config.yml').freeze

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection($CONFIG[:connection])

s = Stock.find_by(isbn: 1234)
s.status = 'CHECKED_OUT'
s.save!
```

Both versions have the same database, the same code, etc. through git. However, on the second server I get the following error:

```
/home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize': SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.book: UPDATE "stock" SET "status" = ? WHERE "stock"."ROWID" = ? (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:212:in `block (2 levels) in exec_query'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:46:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:185:in `yield_shares'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:45:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:209:in `block in exec_query'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in log'
    from /home/web/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:611:in `block in log'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:603:in `log'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:208:in `exec_query'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:239:in `exec_delete'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:140:in `update'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:17:in `update'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb:85:in `_update_record'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:575:in `_update_record'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:80:in `_update_record'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:292:in `_update_record'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `block in _update_record'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_update_callbacks'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:344:in `_update_record'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:107:in `_update_record'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:563:in `create_or_update'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:336:in `block in create_or_update'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:336:in `create_or_update'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:162:in `save!'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save!'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:43:in `save!'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in save!'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:384:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `block in transaction'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:194:in `block in within_new_transaction'
    from /home/web/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:191:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:235:in `transaction'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:210:in `transaction'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:381:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `save!'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:46:in `save!'
    from test.rb:12:in `<main>'
D, [2018-02-04T19:36:39.046660 #26810] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mStock Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "stock".* FROM "stock" WHERE "stock"."isbn" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["isbn", 1234], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-02-04T19:36:39.055100 #26810] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
D, [2018-02-04T19:36:39.056339 #26810] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "stock" SET "status" = ? WHERE "stock"."ROWID" = ?[0m  [["status", "CHECKED_OUT"], ["ROWID", 1]]
D, [2018-02-04T19:36:39.056522 #26810] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[31mrollback transaction[0m
```

The interesting thing is that the table it says doesn't exist is not used at all in the query (as you can see in the logged queries). The Stock model has a `belongs_to :book, foreign_key: 'isbn'` which stops the error when removed. However, changing any column other than `status` does not cause the error.

The servers *do* have different versions of ActiveRecord and SQLite, however I am more interested in why this behavior is occurring so that I can prevent it in the future. The code works on ActiveRecord 2.6.8, but fails on 2.6.14. Is there any obvious reason why this would happen?

Comment: I believe so. They are identical on both systems, which makes me think that the error has to be something else.